# A right answer getting downvoted without any special reasons

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I see wherever [this user](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/67/ahmadi), it's has got downvoted (sometimes, heavily) without any comments mentioning what is wrong with it. I mean more the situations where they are valid ones. I wonder if it's because of the past impression users got by his/her answers.

I think this is not a nice thing to see happening in the community. I think a comment is really needed in this case, since the user is a quite active one and needs to know for further improvement.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/173/42)

Answer (score 8):

It is wrong to DV someone based on personal affiliations or what impression people have about the person. As for the person in question, in my opinion, he gets down voted justly sometimes but unjustly sometimes. It is not wrong to write in Jaffiri fiqh point of view. The person gets DVed in my opinion when :

1. He attacks other sects or affiliations.
2. He does the "exposing" business or leaves attacking comments on other opinions.
3. When he writes reference like "online chat with this mufti". Though it is not wrong and a person following his own school of thought will find it useful, some people might consider it not good. Hence, it becomes an unpopular answer and gets DV ed.

Other than that, he might get DV ed unjustly too, which in my opinion, is very bad for this site and should be prevented.

Comment: Well, even for those three cases, I think the user only deserve downvote for that special case, not in general. Which means I agree if you mean what I said.

Comment: @Gigili Yes, I agree. That will be unjust.

Comment: what you consider attack to other sects I consider it this Hadith of prophet: "accept truth even if it is bitter" when truth is bitter for a sect it is considered as attack. but in fact it is bitter truth. nyway I have no intend to attack anyone even if it is considered attack by a sect. we should try to know true Islam out of 73 sect and accept truth even if has conflict with beliefs of our sect. changing sect should be easy for a Muslim who has no dogma about his sect.

Comment: @Ahmadi You have reasons to believe you have the ultimate truth. But, don't oblige me to accept that is the truth. Because, I am not obliging you to follow my methodology. I expect the same respect and consideration from you.

Comment: @Ershad I never oblige anyone to accept any belief. this is against Islam: http://tanzil.net/#2:256 "There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion. The right course has become clear from the wrong. So whoever disbelieves in Taghut and believes in Allah has grasped the most trustworthy handhold with no break in it. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing."  I only try to clear the 73 sect prophet said to truth seekers can decide easily and find real Islam among 73 sect prophet said. and I am aware this will be bitter for members of 72 sect. I seek upvote from Allah not from people.

Comment: @Ahmadi Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 6):

I hate to see it, but I think we're starting to see "alliegances" and people down-up voting based on who they like, who is their friend, who supports them and their beliefs, and who is the same label of Muslim -- whatever they subscribe to.

Don't DV the messenger, I'm just saying that this is my impression when I surf the site. I don't do this, I subscribe to Dynamic's methodology.

The user in question had a lot of low-quality answers initially which I DVed. He has some great ones which I up-voted. No issue here.

I have also seen a similar trend on my own posts -- some answers which I have +4, +6, +9 etc. suddenly get a -1 out of nowhere. When I check my reputation history, I see a bunch of DVes in a short amount of time.

**Please, keep your personal opinions to yourself.** Islam.SE is a site based on mutual tolerance and acceptance of "other" types of Muslims who believe things differently from what you believe. **It's not a problem. Vote based on the authenticity and clarity of the answer,** not on the underlying beliefs of the individual.

Answer (score 5):

As a user, I do not down-vote based on the person. I down-vote based on the answer. If I see an answer that is not useful, I down-vote, and, unless I am in a hurry, leave a comment.

The user in question has had some very good answers, and some that were not so good. I up/down voted based on that answer, not previous ones, and expect others did the same. If not, I encourage you to do so.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of the fact. I wanted to let the community know about it. I mostly upvote to neutralize the downvotes made by other users. Don't downvote when you're in a hurry, you can vote the answer down later.

Comment: @Gigili It might be me. It might not be me. Depends on the post, and whether I think it deserves an up/down vote, like I said. But why are you neutralizing posts? Vote up if you think it deserves it, not if you feel sorry for it.

Comment: That's what I said and why I posted this, I neutralize the unfair downvotes. Other cases are none of my concern.

Comment: @Gigili, counter down-voting is also not a helpful action. You should not up-vote to cancel other people's down-votes if you don't think the post doesn't deserve an up-vote without the down-votes.

Comment: @Gigili, How did you justify unfairness so readily? It is itself a bad thing to say *unfair* to majority of downvoter. Isn't it?

Comment: @Anwar Shah: So readily? I don't get what you mean. I mean when a correct answer has got heavily downvoted.

Comment: @Gigili, How to you find that it is correct? when Community here decided that it is not correct. It may be correct to you, but votes decided that it was not correct.

Answer (score -1):

Though I have never down voted for him. But I can tell you why he is being down voted. If you see any of his answers, he answers from his own sect of view. Though Islam doesn't recognize sects but I have seen him giving answers from jaffari point of view. which to some extent means that he is not giving the clear Islamic prespective of answers rather Jaffari(Islamic) point of view. which is actually wrong.

Comment: What? Even if he speaks of his own sect, there are two possibilities: 1) it's the same about other sects which means the answers are right 2) it's not the same so the user mentioned his answer is specific to that sect. That's a perfectly good thing to add to one's answer.

Comment: Would it be fine for you if he dropped the mentioning of Jaffari in his answers? There are various schools among Muslims and they have different opinions on many issues. The fact that other answers don't mention what school the views belong to and answer as if there is a consensus among Muslims on issues seems much more troubling to me.

Comment: Given the site is about Islam and not a particular sect, so I would Ideally prefer answer from Islamic point of view rather than from a particular sect of view. But in the end choice is in the hands of answer poster and btw do you know that sects always differ in opinion among themselves, e-g shia and sunnis

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "from Islamic point". The problem is that there is not *an* Islamic viewpoint, there are Islamic viewpoints! These schools of thought are all Islamic and are acceptable. Check [Islamic schools and branches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_schools_and_branches) and [Madhab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madh%27hab) and [Amman message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amman_message).  I guess you think the school you belong to is the correct Islamic viewpoint and others are just something else. I can assure you that others have similar thoughts about their school.

Comment: if each answer specify the sect and school then all views will be added. please note this is a collaborative and wiki based website and one use should not (and can not) answer from all view points of Muslims. usually each user is professional only about his own sect/madhab not all. such person be professional in all sects and madhab I do not think exist in earth or if exist is very rare. only God has such perfect knowledge.