# Why do you lose 1 point from your reputation if you downvote a question?

Tags: bug, down-votes

I recently downvoted two answers on the same page and somehow I lost 2 points as is shown on my profile.

Is this a new update?

Comment: @Medi1Saif : Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voting is a privilege which one earns by participation or activity on the site.

It is also a way to express whether one finds an answer helpful or not.

We have already a bunch of meta posts on the topic of down-voting so it might be useless to explain rather than to link to them:

- [How and when should I downvote answers?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/how-and-when-should-i-downvote-answers)
- [Disagreement should not be a basis for down-voting](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/746/disagreement-should-not-be-a-basis-for-down-voting)
- [If you get a downvote, it is not the end of the world](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/if-you-get-a-downvote-it-is-not-the-end-of-the-world)
- [Identifying disagreement-related voting biases](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2949/identifying-disagreement-related-voting-biases)
- [Is it proper in Islam to down vote instead of reply?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/is-it-proper-in-islam-to-down-vote-instead-of-reply)
- [Why does this SE site issue out more downvotes without comments than other ones?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/why-does-this-se-site-issue-out-more-downvotes-without-comments-than-other-ones)
- [A right answer getting downvoted without any special reasons](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201/a-right-answer-getting-downvoted-without-any-special-reasons)
- [Try to help others improve their posts before down-voting them](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188/try-to-help-others-improve-their-posts-before-down-voting-them)

From this we may learn reputation can be earned and lost, and it shouldn't be the most important thing for us rather than being helpful and encouraging helpful posts: good questions, well elaborated questions and answers, useful answers etc.

So now you down-voted and lost some reputation note that while you lose 1 reputation point by down-voting, you may gain 5 by asking a good question, 10 if you answer one or even 15 if your answer was accepted.

Also note that if you down-voted a question or answer which really had clear issues (like an answer that misses  the topic, is rude or abusive, spam etc. or a question that is not well elaborated nor well researched or clearly off-topic) and it got enough down-votes to be deleted/closed/put on hold by the system or deleted/closed/put on hold by a moderator (which we in cases try to avoid to help the community to develop as stack exchange is a community moderated platform) you may get your lost reputation points back. This is how stack exchange shows that it trusts your voting.

As you may down-vote for whatever human reason: Hate the author, not agree with the content of the post, you follow a different madhhab/view etc.. Therefore down-voting should be considered to be paired with a comment or by "up-voting" a prior comment to show the author of the post that something is wrong and needs to be changed.

For more information refer to [this explanation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) about reputation and how it might be gained or lost in our help center.

Note that in cases -which are not quoted in the above link- you may even loose more reputation (if a user account was deleted last October for example I lost 30 and 50 points at once or a voting was reversed: a user up voted several posts of you in a short time, all his voting would be reversed).

Comment: Where can one suggest to delete this feature?

Comment: @Tarik On [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Oh, oké. Thank you.